# SQL Query to fetch data for following conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to fetch the person details from table person where it contain Type as Mail.

Should fetch only those employees who have type as mail but do not have HOME and also having valid person_address.

A valid person_address is something which do not have a period or comma or quote character or not a po box.

**Existing data:**

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════════╦══════╗
║ person_ID ║ Person_address  ║ Type ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════╬══════╣
║         1 ║ 5/40 The Avenu  ║ Mail ║
║         2 ║ 5/40 The Avenu  ║ Mail ║
║         2 ║ P O BOX 567     ║ Home ║
║         3 ║ post office 76  ║ Mail ║
║         4 ║ 5/40 The Avenu  ║ Mail ║
║         5 ║ 5/40 The Avenu  ║ Mail ║
║         5 ║ POST OFFICE 67  ║ Home ║
║         6 ║ PO BOX 567      ║ Mail ║
║         7 ║ 5/40 The Avenu  ║ Mail ║
║         8 ║ 5/40 The Avenu. ║ Mail ║
║         9 ║ P O BOX 567     ║ Mail ║
║        10 ║ post office 76  ║ Mail ║
║        11 ║ PO BOX 567      ║ Mail ║
║        12 ║ 5/40 The Avenu  ║ Home ║
║        12 ║ POST OFFICE 67  ║ Mail ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════╩══════╝
```

**Desired output:**

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════╦══════╗
║ person_ID ║ Person_address ║ Type ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════╬══════╣
║         1 ║ 5/40 The Avenu ║ Mail ║
║         4 ║ 5/40 The Avenu ║ Mail ║
║         7 ║ 5/40 The Avenu ║ Mail ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: i am not understanding your desired output: if  1 ║ 5/40 The Avenu ║ Mail  is valid then why not   2 ║ 5/40 The Avenu  ║ Mail

Comment: because it has a type of HOME

Answer (score 1):

What is your DB .Anyway give this a try..

```
select * from test
minus
select * from test
where id in (
select id  from test
where Typee ='Home'
or upper(address) like  any ('%''%' , '%.%' , '%,%' ,'%P O BOX%' , '%POST%' ,'%PO BOX%'));
```

Just saw your output is changed...:)

Comment: @Vishal : What i got from his desired output is , that he do not want any id  in output which contains the , . pobox etc.

Comment: can you paste your output as well? then why not  2 ║ 5/40 The Avenu  ║ Mail  valid?

Comment: id address typee
2 5/40 The Avenu Mail
2 P O BOX 567 Home
3 post office 76 Mail
5 5/40 The Avenu Mail
5 POST OFFICE 67 Home
6 PO BOX 567 Mail
8 5/40 The Avenu. Mail
9 P O BOX 567 Mail
10 post office 76 Mail
11 PO BOX 567 Mail
12 POST OFFICE 67 Mail
12 5/40 The Avenu Home

Comment: the above output is from second query after minus.. final one is like
1    1 The Avenu  Mail Mail
2    4 5/40 The Avenu Mail
3    7 5/40 The Avenu Mail

Comment: @Vishal i think my query is returning correct result as well..in case your db is not supporting ' like any ' then you can separate each condition and use union..its returing the desired 3 rows as output..its showing extra 1,2,3 as i have pasted it from sql assistant answer window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to achieve the same

```
select * from person 
where person_id not in (select person_id from person where type='Home')
and person_address not like '%.%' 
and person_address not like '%,%'
and person_address not like 'P%O BOX%'
and upper(person_address) not like 'POST%OFFICE%';
```

You can simplify these multiple like condition using [**Regexp_like**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) like below:

```
select * from person 
         where person_id not in (select person_id from person where type='Home')
           and not regexp_like (person_address,'(P*O*BOX|POST OFFICE|[.,])','i');
```

You can check your desired output in [**DEMO SQL  FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63f2d/1)

Comment: its also returning  8 || 5/40 The Avenu || Mail along with desired output

Comment: @Vishal : No it won't. I'm not getting

Comment: I have executed above query.. it shown 3 records for me. and ideally it should show.. i thing he missed in showing desired output

Comment: @Vishal. If you see, for that row there is a **dot** at the end(*5/40 The Avenu*.) in the address. OP wants  not to display addresses with dot. So it should not be displaying in the output.

Comment: @Vishal. Fine..Thank you for testing it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from datas group by id having count(*)=1) as temp 

WHERE type REGEXP "^Mail$"

AND address NOT REGEXP "P O BOX|post office|[.,'\"]+"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  person_ID  Person_address  Type 
 -----------------------------------------
      1      5/40 The Avenu  Mail

      4      5/40 The Avenu  Mail

      7      5/40 The Avenu  Mail
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT 1 AS person_id, '5/40 The Avenu' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 AS person_id, '5/40 The Avenu' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 AS person_id, 'P O BOX 567' AS person_address, 'Home' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 3 AS person_id, 'post office 76' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 4 AS person_id, '5/40 The Avenu' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 5 AS person_id, '5/40 The Avenu' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 5 AS person_id, 'post office 76' AS person_address, 'Home' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 6 AS person_id, 'PO BOX 567' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 7 AS person_id, '5/40 The Avenu' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 8 AS person_id, '5/40 The Avenu.' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 9 AS person_id, 'P O BOX 567' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 10 AS person_id, 'post office 76' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 11 AS person_id, 'PO BOX 567' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 12 AS person_id, '5/40 The Avenu' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 12 AS person_id, 'POST OFFICE 67' AS person_address, 'Mail' AS TYPE FROM dual )

SELECT x.* FROM x, 
               (SELECT person_id, 
                count(person_id) count_x 
                FROM x GROUP BY person_id) y    
        WHERE x.person_id = y.person_id 
        AND count_x = 1   
        AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (x.person_address, '(post office|PO BOX|POST OFFICE|P O BOX|[.])');
```

OUTPUT will be:

```
 PERSON_ID PERSON_ADDRESS  TYPE
---------- --------------- ----
        1 5/40 The Avenu Mail 
        4 5/40 The Avenu Mail 
        7 5/40 The Avenu Mail
```